# How to add HTML content at select2 dropdown box

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I've used [Select2 plugin](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) for tag input. [Here is the fiddle of my basic work](http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/LfhL33kc/1/). I need showing "used number" of each options/tags at dropdown box like this way:

[image]

I've created a class for that number in my CSS (`.used-number`). But, I don't understand how can I add that number for each options at my HTML file. Is there a way to add those something like this(or any other way):

```
$(".tag").select2({
     data:[{tag: 'red',text:'3',className: 'used-number'},{tag: 'green',text:'12',className: 'used-number'},{tag: 'blue',text:'5', className: 'used-number'},{tag: 'black',text:'7'}]
});
```

});

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `tags` array must contain objects with the keys `id` and `text`. You can add more keys if you need (for your case, I've added the key `qt` that represents the number).

To add HTML to the option you need to change the default `formatResult` function. With the following code, the numbers appear to the tags that exist (that is, the tags passed to the select2). For the options created on the fly, the number will not appear.

```
$(".tag").select2({
    tags:[
        {id: "red", text: "red", qt: 3},
        {id: "green", text: "green", qt: 12},
        {id: "blue", text: "blue", qt: 5},
        {id: "black", text: "black", qt: 7}
    ],
    formatResult: function(result) {
        if (result.qt === undefined) {
            return result.text;
        }

        return result.text
            + "<span class='used-number'>"
            + result.qt
            + "</span>";
    }
});
```

See the [forked fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fc56928s/5/).

Comment: This functionality works. But, problem is at my fiddle, you'll look that you can input your own tag. But, at your fiddle, free-hand tag can't be make

Comment: This will be resolved if I use tags instead of data. But, at that time, suggestion box's text showed "undefined" in place of number for random text. I want, for random text nothing will be showed in place of number. http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/fc56928s/2/

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand that from your question. I have edited my answer and the fiddle in order to fit your needs.

Comment: Please note that in version 4 the method name `formatResult` has been renamed to `templateResult`. https://select2.github.io/announcements-4.0.html