# Appending span to select

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, bootstrap-select

I have been able to create a static bootstrap-select list in my site using HTML

```
<select id="testDrop" class="selectpicker input-lg form-control">
    <optgroup label="Constraints Applied">
        <option data-content="<span style='display: inline-block;min-width:80px;'>Day 1</span><span class='label label-success'>Any Room</span>"></option>
        <option data-content="<span style='display: inline-block;min-width:80px;'>Day 2</span><span class='label label-success'>3 from 30 available</span>"></option>
        <option data-content="<span style='display: inline-block;min-width:80px;'>Day 3</span><span class='label label-success'>Of Type: Computer Lab</span>"></option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="No Constraints Applied">
        <option>Day 4</option>
        <option>Day 5</option>
        <option>Day 6</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

[image]

Although I am unsure how to create a dynamic version using jQuery/JavaScript?

### HTML

```
<select id="plannerStartSelector" style="width:300px;">
</select>
```

### js

```
var dateSelect = m.format('DD/MM/YYYY') + " (" + dow + ")";
var spanOpt;
if (problems === true) {
    spanOpt = "<span style='display: inline-block;min-width:80px;'>" + dateSelect + "</span><span class='label label-danger'>Problem</span>"
} else {
    spanOpt = "<span style='display: inline-block;min-width:80px;'>" + dateSelect + "</span>";
}

$(this.ui.plannerStartSelector).append($("<option></option>").attr("data-content", spanOpt));

$(this.ui.plannerStartSelector).select2({
    placeholder: "- Select a Date -",
});
```

Any ideas how I can achieve this? Searching online has not brought me any answers. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is a server involved or is this a standalone page?

Comment: A server is involved, yes.

Comment: I would recommend producing the HTML with whatever templating system your server uses. Javascript should generally be used for light manipulations of already-existing HTML, not creating it.

Comment: Ahh yes, the thought of using a template didn't cross my mind. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add HTML content at select2 dropdown box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25266970/how-to-add-html-content-at-select2-dropdown-box)